# Add Meteor login google oauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to create a simple login button for button in Meteor using google oauth. I executed the following commands

mrt create accounts
mrt add accounts-google
mrt add accounts-ui

I gutted the default html/css/js and added:
client/index.html
server/config.js

here is config.js

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
   service: "google"
});
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "google",
    clientId: "[redacted]",
    secret: "[redacted]"
})
```

and here is index.html

```
<head>
    <title>Accounts</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{loginButtons}}
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{currentUser.profile.login}}
    {{/if}}
</body>
```

However, with the config I get the following error when I try to start the server:
W20140729-22:22:42.461(-5)? (STDERR) 
W20140729-22:22:42.844(-5)? (STDERR) /home/tim/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140729-22:22:42.845(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140729-22:22:42.845(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140729-22:22:42.846(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
W20140729-22:22:42.846(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/config.js:1:71
W20140729-22:22:42.847(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/config.js:11:3
W20140729-22:22:42.847(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/tim/Desktop/accounts/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
W20140729-22:22:42.849(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140729-22:22:42.850(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/tim/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140729-22:22:42.851(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/tim/Desktop/accounts/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8

The config is from an old tutorial so I'm wondering if the code is outdated, but I'm having trouble finding anything more recent. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: your stacktrace says that Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration is undefined. That's what is going on.

Comment: You need to use {{> loginButtons}} and the name of the google user will be stored in currentUser.profile.name, note that any other field (google id, email, picture...) has to be copied from user.services.google in the Accouns.onCreateUser callback server-side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is add the service-configuration package using:

```
meteor add service-configuration
```

cheers!

Comment: that did it! note you also have to change accounts.js to use "ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({})" and remove